# Output date into specific column using bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, date

I want to output the date into a csv column using a bash script ignoring the header. I have this but it only gives the day of the week abbreviated and not does not place it in a specific column:

```
date | awk '{print $1}' >> date.csv
```

Here is the csv I want to have after command is run:

```
bash_script1,bash_script2,bash_script3
Thu Mar  2 03:11:01 EST 2023,Tue Mar 21 05:39:01 EDT 2023,Thu Mar  2 04:19:01 EST 2023
Thu Mar  2 04:19:01 EST 2023,Tue Mar 21 05:40:01 EDT 2023,Thu Mar  2 04:20:01 EST 2023
Thu Mar  2 04:20:01 EST 2023,Tue Mar 21 05:41:01 EDT 2023,Fri Mar  3 03:11:01 EST 2023
Fri Mar  3 03:11:01 EST 2023,,
Fri Mar  3 03:12:02 EST 2023,,
```

I have multiple bash scripts on a cron schedule and I want to know when they are executed and instead of making individual text files with:

```
date >> bash_script2.txt
```

I want to put all the scripts inside one spreadsheet, one script per column. During my research I could not find out how to output a command like 'date' into a csv file. I found a lot of ways to output specific text or variables into a csv file but not a command.

I simply want to print the output of 'date' into a specific column of a csv file ignoring the header with bash.

With date variable output:

```
TheDate=`date +"%F %T %Z"`

printf "\n$TheDate,," >> date.csv #would go into first column
printf "\n,$TheDate," >> date.csv #would go into second column
printf "\n,,$TheDate" >> date.csv #would go into third column
```

The above works but printf doesn't seem to know how to use up the first available blank line in the column:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| script1 | script2 | script3 | script4 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| date    |         |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| date    |         |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|         | date    |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|         |         | date    |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|         |         | date    |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a little awful script that does something similar to what you want:

```
awk -i inplace  -v myvar="$(date)" 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="," ; flag = 0}; \
{if (!flag && $2=="") {flag=1; print $1, myvar , $3} else print $0}' date.csv
```

this script only outputs to the second column, and only ever outputs if it finds a line in which the second column exists and is empty.

it can be modified to output to the first or third columns easily, if you know awk. Does this do what you wanted to begin with?
----- EDIT -----

ok i got a script a bit more refined.
file `col.awk`:

```c
BEGIN{
    FS=OFS=",";
    flag=0;
    total=3;

    "date +\"%F %T %Z\"" | getline date;
} 
{
    if(!flag && $which==""){
        flag=1;
        sub(/.*/,date,$which) ; 
    }
    print 
}
ENDFILE{
    if(!flag ){
        count=which-1
        while(count >0){
            printf ",";
            count--;
        }
        printf  date
        count=total-which
        while(count >0){
            printf ",";
            count--;
        }
            printf "\n";
    }
}
```

you run this with something like:

`awk -i inplace -v which=2 -f col.awk date.csv`

edit2: fixed something with ENDFILE to allow inplace editing

Comment: I'm building a script based on what you wrote, the in place date variable is great!

Comment: I can't get it to work.

Comment: check my edit. i think its a bit more robust now.

Comment: Can you explain the variables? What is "flag=" and "total="? Column amount? And what is "which=2" in the command you need to run?

Comment: awk: not an option: -i, is what I'm getting running that command. Guess I'm using gawk and not GNU awk. Can you rewrite it for gawk? I tired command: awk col.awk test.csv > tmp.csv && mv -f tmp.csv sample.csv, didn't work.

Comment: I had to install gawk and now i'm checking it out, I think it's working

Comment: Hell of a job with the script, works perfectly. Hopefully others can make use of it as well. If you or someone could explain the flag portion in a little more detail it would be appreciated.

Comment: glad be helpful! just to clarify, the "total" variable is the number of columns, and "which" is the column you want to add to, but you prolly figured that out by now. i forgot to say my version of awk is GNU Awk 5.1.0, but i guess you could get it to work with other awks.

Answer (score 0):

> I found a lot of ways to output specific text or variables into a csv file but not a command.

The store the `date` output into a variable, and proceed on your way:

```
$ TheDate=`date`
$ echo $TheDate
Mon 27 Mar 2023 06:01:59 PM CDT
```

Plain old `date` isn't very sortable, though.  Try this instead:

```
$ TheDate=`date +"%F %T %Z"`
$ echo $TheDate
2023-03-27 18:04:15 CDT
```

EDIT: Ah, you're making a matrix.

How do you know if a script runs on a certain date?

Can you get all that information *before* appending to date.csv?

For example:

```
TheDate=`date +"%F %T %Z"`
if [[ Script_1_ran ]]; then Date1=$TheDate; else Date1=; fi
if [[ Script_2_ran ]]; then Date2=$TheDate; else Date2=; fi
if [[ Script_3_ran ]]; then Date3=$TheDate; else Date3=; fi
if [[ Script_4_ran ]]; then Date4=$TheDate; else Date4=; fi

echo ${Date1},${Date2},${Date3},${Date4}
```

EDIT 2:

A function:

```
script_ran()
{
    # $1 is the script number (1,2,3,4)
    local X=$(($1 + 64))
    local ndx=`printf \\$(printf '%03o' $X)` # converts to A,B,C,D
    local TimeStamp=`date +"%F %T %Z"`
    sed -i -e '$s/${X}/${TimeStamp}/g' date.csv
}
```

At the beginning of the day (presumably in cron), run this to add today's line:

```
date +"%F,A,B,C,D" >> date.csv
```

When script 1 runs, run this function:

```
script_ran 1
```

Ditto scripts 2,3 and 4.

At the end of today, 27 March, if only scripts 1 and 3 ran, the last line would look something like:

```
2023-03-27,2023-03-27 05:12:34,B,2023-03-27 14:23:45,D
```

Thus, you'd have timestamps for when each job ran.  The placeholders for jobs that didn't run would still be there, and could be removed at the end of the day.

Comment: The time zone is a great addition, thank you for your help. The variable makes sense now.

Comment: Having a little trouble outputting the variable into a specific column though, can you help with that? Tried: awk -F '$TheDate' 'NR > 1 {print $1}' date.csv

Comment: That's a different question... :D.  It also depends on the nature of the "other inputs": where are you getting the script names?  Just as importantly, current `date` output has nothing to do with when a script executed.

Comment: I'm just writing the script names into the first line of a csv file. The script names only show me what script was executed so I'm manually entering the script names into a csv file. And then I want to output date into a specific column according to the script name so I can know when it was executed. Hope that's clear.

Comment: So maybe to be more clear, if bash_script1 executed today it would make an entry into the bash_script1 column with today's date.

Comment: "it would make an entry into the bash_script1 column with today's date".  Is "it" the process you asked about in the question?  *Please* edit the question with more description.

Comment: Based on your variable output:
printf "\n$TheDate," >> date.csv = first column
printf "\n,$TheDate," >> date.csv = second column
printf "\n,$TheDate" >> date.csv = third column

Comment: it = the bash script

Comment: I just added a variable to my original question.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it's better to do something like `echo "${TheDate},${ScriptName} >> date.csv`.

Comment: I guess I failed at explaining myself. I just want to put a date stamp into a specific column of a spreadsheet.

Comment: Does my edited answer solve your problem?

Comment: No because each script runs in a separate file but really the scripts are irrelevant here I just used that as a reference. I simply want to put a date stamp into a specific column of a spreadsheet. The column name can be anything: one,two,three,four